# QFile open file for writing fails

Tags: c++, qt, qfile

I'm trying to open file and write some text data into it.

```
QFile out(":/test.txt");
if (!out.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setText(out.errorString());
    msgBox.exec();
    return;
}
```

But it fails with "Unknown error". 
(Qt 4.6, Wnidows XP SP3)

Comment: If you just want to write, use WriteOnly. (But that won't work for resources files anyway, as Roku explained).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

":/test.txt" is a name of a [resource file](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/resources.html) embedded to the executable and you can't write to it. Change the file name for example to "C:/test.txt".

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your QFile constructor argument

`QFile out(":/test.txt");`

to a correct path that could be

`QFile out("./test.txt");`

or

`QFile out("C:/test.txt");`